# mysql (with db2) many to many get all records with given parameter

Tags: mysql, db2, many-to-many

Given the tables with a many-to-many relation

```
employee
--------
id
firstname
lastname
...

service
--------
id
name_nl
...

employee_service
----------------
employee_id
service_id
...
```

I'm building a search function and what I would like is when someone enters a service (for example: CIV) it retrieves every employee that has that service + every other service/function/keyword he or she has. I got it to work so far, but the query doesn't include the other services.

```
   SELECT e.firstname, e.lastname, s.name_nl 
     FROM DB.employee e 
LEFT JOIN DB.function f ON (f.id = e.function_id) 
LEFT JOIN DB.employee_service es ON (e.id = es.employee_id) 
LEFT JOIN DB.service s ON (es.service_id = s.id) 
LEFT JOIN DB.employee_keyword ek ON (e.id = ek.employee_id) 
LEFT JOIN DB.keyword k ON (ek.keyword_id = k.id) 
    WHERE e.deleted IS NULL
      AND s.name_nl = 'CIV'
 ORDER BY e.firstname asc
```

So this gives me back a John Doe with the service CIV, but John has many other services that I would like to have retrieved as well...

If anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated!
Thnx in advanced!

ps: I would be glad to clearify some things if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `JOIN` again with `employee_service`, like:

```
    SELECT e.firstname, e.lastname, s.name_nl,
           s2.name_nl 
      FROM DB.employee e 
 LEFT JOIN DB.function f ON (f.id = e.function_id) 
 LEFT JOIN DB.employee_service es ON (e.id = es.employee_id) 
 LEFT JOIN DB.service s ON (es.service_id = s.id) 
 LEFT JOIN DB.employee_keyword ek ON (e.id = ek.employee_id) 
 LEFT JOIN DB.keyword k IN (ek.keyword_id = k.id) 
 LEFT JOIN DB.employee_service es2 ON (e.id = es2.employee_id) 
 LEFT JOIN DB.service s2 ON (es2.service_id = s2.id)
     WHERE e.deleted IS NULL
       AND s.name_nl = 'CIV'
       AND s2.id<>s.id
  ORDER BY e.firstname asc
```

Comment: Just tested it, works like a charm!
Thanx man!

I'm wondering though, are there any other ways of achieving this, or is this the standard procedure?

Comment: Well... it is how I do it always... If you find another way, please let us know.